# Changing screen orientation while questions are loading crashes app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Changing screen orientation (rotating device) while questions are still loading (progressbar still showing) will crash the app.

Here is the stack trace.

```
10-31 20:59:44.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25383): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-31 20:59:44.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25383): java.lang.NullPointerException: [v0.1.58] 
10-31 20:59:44.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25383):    at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.common.MarvinFragment.updateActionBar(MarvinFragment.java:81)
10-31 20:59:44.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25383):    at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.SingleSiteFragment.access$000(SingleSiteFragment.java:37)
10-31 20:59:44.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25383):    at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.SingleSiteFragment$SingleSiteListResult.onHandled(SingleSiteFragment.java:260)
10-31 20:59:44.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25383):    at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.common.MarvinListOfThingsFragment$GetDataTask.onPostExecute(MarvinListOfThingsFragment.java:281)
10-31 20:59:44.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25383):    at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.common.MarvinListOfThingsFragment$GetDataTask.onPostExecute(MarvinListOfThingsFragment.java:194)
10-31 20:59:44.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25383):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
10-31 20:59:44.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25383):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
10-31 20:59:44.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25383):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
10-31 20:59:44.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25383):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-31 20:59:44.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25383):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-31 20:59:44.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25383):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
10-31 20:59:44.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25383):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-31 20:59:44.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25383):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-31 20:59:44.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25383):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
10-31 20:59:44.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25383):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
10-31 20:59:44.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25383):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Edit:**
This also happens when you press the back button while content is still loading.

So basically the activity gets destroyed or `MarvinFragment` gets detached from the activity before `GetDataTask.onPostExecute()` gets called / finishes.

And in `onPostExecute()` you're updating the actionbar, so you're probably calling `getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar()`.

`getSherlockActivity()` will return `null` in this case, hence the `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed in version 0.1.61 coming out later tonight. I also apologize to any of my coworkers who saw me trying to be really quick at rotating my phone around like a fool.